# Detecting the change in inputs (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are several inputs and I want it to detect the variability in the input and give it the result. Currently, it works statically, I want to make it dynamically detect the digit change in the inputs.

I can do this with only 1 input but how can I do it for multiple inputs?

```js
var allHaveSameValue = $(".inputclass").toArray().every(function(input, index, inputs) {
  return input.value === inputs[0].value;
});

console.log(allHaveSameValue);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="inputclass" value="1"/>
<input type="text" class="inputclass" value="1"/>
<input type="text" class="inputclass" value="1"/>
<input type="text" class="inputclass" value="1"/>
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use `change` event listeners on all the inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to the input event to run the check.

```js
let $inputClass = $('.inputclass');
$inputClass.on('input', function(e){
  let val = $(this).val();
  let allHaveSameValue = $inputClass.toArray().every(input => input.value === val);
  console.log(allHaveSameValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="inputclass" value="1"/>
<input type="text" class="inputclass" value="1"/>
<input type="text" class="inputclass" value="1"/>
<input type="text" class="inputclass" value="1"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but sorry, I asked the question wrong. Each input ID value would be different. Could you please help with this?

Comment: @Emre6 It doesn't matter what the ids are. My solution selects the inputs based on their class.